# Local Notification Not showing up when app opens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a local notification set up. Once its fired, lets say my app is in "sleep" mode that is home button pressed or i quit it.  Now the notification is received.  I see red tag on my app and when I click on the app, it should fire `didReceiveLocalNotification` but it does't. How can I make it do that when I open my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is only called when your application is running in the foreground.  If you see a badge and click on the App to start it, then you need to process the local notification using `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) To get at your local notification in either of these two methods, use `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` as a key to the options dictionary.

[edit] From the UILocalNotification documentation:

> if the local notification only badges the application icon, and the
>   user in response launches the application, the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method is invoked, but no
>   UILocalNotification object is included in the options dictionary.

Comment: the launch options return nil..... i can see the notification on notification bar but launch options return nil when i open app

Comment: Was the launchOptions dictionary nil?  If not, what was its content?

Comment: Yes that is wrong. It is nil. It must return something. I have tried putting a simple notification in didEnterBackground. Opened app, pressed home button. Close the app using Xcode and then after getting notification, retort it using Xcode. Still nil.

Comment: [See edit.]  Sadly, I just tried to implement it and I am seeing the local notification but I'm not seeing a call to application:will... Sorry.

Comment: how am i suppose to do that then?

Comment: Note I did get a 'didReceiveLocalNotification' - so it appears that in my test I was still in the foreground.  Seems you should be getting either didReceiveLocalNotification or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  Not sure what is up.  Just be sure to assign an alertBody string.

Comment: well i do get didReceive but when app is quit it goes to Finish one. and i don't get launching options.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)alarmNotification
    {
       NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

      NSDate *newdate = timePicker.date;

      NSLog(@"pickerdate:%@",newdate);

      NSDate *pickerDate =[newdate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*1];

      NSLog(@"pickerdate:%@",timePicker.date);

      // Break the date up into components
      NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |      NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                  fromDate:pickerDate];
      NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
     // Set up the fire time
      NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
     [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
     [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
     [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
     [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
     // Notification will fire in one minute
     [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
     [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
      NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
      [dateComps release];

      localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
      if (localNotif == nil)
         return;
      localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
       localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

     // Notification details
      localNotif.alertBody = txtMeetingName.text;

    // Set the action button
      localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View!", nil);

       localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

       // Specify custom data for the notification
       NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
       localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber =1;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


      }
```

Then implement this code......

```
      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
     // Handle the notificaton when the app is running
      NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:notif.repeatInterval fromDate:notif.fireDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
     // you can set your own sound 
      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/win.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

     NSError *error;

      UIAlertView *alertView =
     [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"move on", nil)
                           message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have to start %@   meeting within 5 minute",notif.alertBody]
                          delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                 otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil), nil];

      notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


      audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
      audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
      if (audioPlayer == nil)
         NSLog(@"error%@",[error description]);
      else
         [audioPlayer play];
      [alertView show];
      [alertView release];   

   }


  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:     (NSInteger)buttonIndex{
     if (buttonIndex==0) {
    [audioPlayer stop];      

     }
    NSLog(@"U HAVE CLICKED BUTTON");
 }
```

hope this will help you.....

Comment: i want to get it in didFinishLaunchOptions, it is working good with didReceive. Actually when app is closed and is opened normally, unlike push notification it never shows up in launchOptons

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting fire date then there have you set the userInfo property of your notification object???
& r u checking it on device or on simulator??

Comment: The notification is launched Just fine. When I click on notification, it does call didReceiveNotification. However unlike Push notifications when app is closed it won't show up in launcher options in didFinishWithLaunchOptions

Comment: Ok..but have  u set the property userinfo of your notification object??

Comment: @MuhammadUmar & r u testing on simulator or on real device

Comment: i know notification launch is fine...but to receive in didfinshlaunching  you have set it when you r fire...that's y m asking have you set that userinfo property